# How to change line in config file

Tags: php

I have a file called settings.php that has all of the settings that the software uses. The problem is that I need users to be able to change the config without editing the file. I know I could do this with `preg_replace` but with dynamic settings like 'Board name' it would get tricky. I've tried a few things that didn't seem to work. I now you're not going to write the code for me, I just need a starting point.

Settings File

```
$settings = array (
    'home_display'=>'home',
    'db_host'=>'localhost',
    'db_user'=>'root',
    'db_password'=>'',
    'db'=>'',
    'login_enabled'=>true,
    'signup_enabled'=>true,
    'site_name'=>'Cheesecake Portal',
    'b_url'=>'beta.cheesecakebb.org',
    'b_email'=>'symbiote@cheesecakeb.org',
    'board_enabled'=>true
    );
```

Comment: how about using a Database to store settings ? Or genereate the file on the fly ?

Comment: If your settings are in one big array, you could serialize it and write a file from it.

Comment: @Bob0t What do you mean generate, like delete and re-create the file?

Comment: @hukir I'll edit the question to show the contents of the file.

Comment: Yes, that's what i mean, it's very simple to do it :)

Comment: why dont u just import the file and change the value at a certain index

Comment: Store the user config in a flat file or database, pull it out when necessary and make it into an array, then use array_merge to override the default config with the user config.

Comment: @Bob0t Good idea actually, never thought of that

Comment: do you just include `settings.php` to get the values?

Comment: @bob0t that would be fine if it's a global change which will affect all users. As these settings change and will constantly changed to suit the users needs. Constantly deleting a file to rewrite personal settings would cause havoc. File deletion is not a solution here. Rather an overly complex and extremely troublesome/problematic flaw

Comment: @DarylGill Actually it's just a settings file for the board to enable/disable registration/signups etc

Comment: So, for clarification. It's a configuration file to be ran on first time installation? And not using what I was thinking; application to serve multiple clients/users & execute custom configurations based on the users need for functionality of the site?.. Am I thinking overly complicated?

Comment: @DarylGill No, this is an overall config for the board. Customizations are stored in the database, Bob0t's answer would work.

Answer (score 0):

The idea i have is to rewrite the file on the fly, even if i think this isnt the best way, it's a way.

```
if( file_exists($mySettingsFile) ){
    include($mySettingsFile);
}
else{
    $settings = array (         // the default settings array
        'home_display'=>'home',
        'db_host'=>'localhost',
        'db_user'=>'root',
        'db_password'=>'',
        'db'=>'',
        'login_enabled'=>true,
        'signup_enabled'=>true,
        'site_name'=>'Cheesecake Portal',
        'b_url'=>'beta.cheesecakebb.org',
        'b_email'=>'symbiote@cheesecakeb.org',
        'board_enabled'=>true
    );
}

// modifiy your settings here searching the key(s) you want to modify

// then put it in the config file
file_put_contents($mySettingsFile, '<?php '.var_export($settings).' ?>');
```

I hope this will illustrate my idea good enough to help you.